# TCP packets stuck in sending queue when running nbd client and nbd server on same machine

Tags: sockets

I was running NBD(network block device) client and NBD server on same matchine binding 127.0.0.1. And a java program writes sequential data to the block device continuously. It works ok within 1~2 hours, but after that, I/O stuck writing to the device.

When checking memory state, I found there is small free memory at that time(<200MB) ; And when checking network state by tcpdump and netstat, I found sending queue in client is almost full, but receiving queue in client, sending queue and receiving queue in server is empty; packet in sending queue keeps retrying to send to server but cannot succeed.

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: what if you restart the server or client process? maybe one of them got freezed? or maybe both?

Comment: server is alive because i tried telnet and send message successfully, but client in kernel cannot process any I/O since then.